# How to eliminate duplicate ids depending on another id

Tags: database, postgresql, jsp

> For my project in jsp ,

I want to insert values into the database

I have shop_Id and clothe_id (there are many shop each one having I'd).

I want to add clothes(there are many clothes and they too have I'd) ,
but for each shop the cloth I'd should not be repeated.
what query should I write to handel it in jsp .

shop_id and clothes_id are coming dynamically

Eg:- a) *correct*

```
      shop I'd       clothe I'd
       0                     0
       0                     1
       0                     2
       1                     0
       1                     1
       1                     2
```

Eg:-b)  *wrong*

```
      shop I'd       clothe I'd
       0                     0
       0                     0 (wrong duplicate value)
       1                     0
```

The eg:- b) cause's data duplication.

What query should I write to Handel it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is managed by your database

```
CREATE TABLE shop_cloth(  
shop_id integer REFERENCES shop,  
cloth_id integer REFERENCES cloth,  
PRIMARY KEY(shop_id, cloth_id) --ensure uniqueness of combinaison shop_id, cloth_id or UNIQUE(shop_id, cloth_id) if you use another field for primary key
);
```

You should learn how works database and SQL (SQL is the language used by most relational database, like PostgreSQL)